# Mozilla Addon SDK - Possible to save changes programmatically via simple-prefs?

Tags: mozilla, firefox-addon-sdk

Is it possible to update a firefox addon's preferences programmatically?

Given the following:

```
const prefs = require("sdk/simple-prefs");
prefs.stringPreference = "some random string";
```

It seems that my update to stringPreference doesn't get persisted, and will revert back to the value in `about:addons` when reloaded, new tabs are opened, etc.

Is this possible?  The docs imply changes are saved automatically but this doesn't seem to be the case..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed the .prefs attribute. It should be:

```
var prefs = require("sdk/simple-prefs").prefs;
```

Notice the **.prefs** at the end of the line.